# Button won't hide before loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a button attached to an IBAction that is supposed to hide before a loop, but it never hides.

```
- (IBAction)method:(id)sender
{
    button.hidden = YES;
    while(...) //button should be hidden while control is in loop but this never happens.
    {
    }
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you bind button with XIB??

Comment: are you sure button isnt nil?

Comment: get the button by sender instead?

Comment: - (IBAction)method:(UIButton *)sender and set [sender setHidden:YES];

Comment: The button is binded with XIB and no it isn't nil. I am able to press the button, but it simply doesn't do anything while control is in the loop. It appears highlighted and that is all.

Comment: If that loop takes a long time and you are executing it on the main thread - it will block the GUI

Comment: Ah thanks Undeph, I'll look into using another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set its `hidden` property, but the view doesn't draw itself right then. It must go through an iteration of the run loop to redraw its contents. If you have a long running synchronous task in your method, control never returns to the run loop until your method exits, so you don't see the effect of setting the `hidden` property.

Consider doing your task asynchronously. Something like

```
button.hidden = YES;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    while (...) {
        // do your work here
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow that's great, but is there any way I can access the UIButton or another UILabel for example from inside the dispatch_async?

Comment: Well you shouldn't access that stuff on the main thread. That said, what do you need to do in a big loop with another button or label?

Comment: It is going to be a loop that monitors an NSString * for change and the loop will break when the NSString value isn't what the loop expects it to be. That NSString will be modified by other methods, also it will belong to the Controller.h.

Comment: You should almost never be blocking the main thread to poll for any condition. Rather, set yourself up to be informed directly of changes via notifications (NSNotificationCenter and / or Key Value Observing), delegation (with protocols), or completion block callbacks. I'd strongly encourage you to reconsider this design and see if you can't adapt it to fit in with the iOS concurrency model and the way the run loop and your application's code interacts.

Comment: I meant "Shouldn't access that stuff OFF the main thread", sorry.